# Proving that number of heads and tails are independent random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

> 1. Let $X$ be a random variable that follows a Poisson distribution of parameters $m$ and let $Y$ be random variable which the conditioned law with $X = n$ follows a binomial distribution with parameters $n,p$.
>
> Prove that: $$  p(Y = k) = \frac{(pm)^k e^{-mp}}{k!} $$
>
> and deduce the nature of $Y$.
>
> During a class, a bored student watches from window the leaves falling from a tree, we admit the number of the leaves fallen from the tree by the end of the class is a random variable $X$ that follows a Poisson distribution of parameter $\lambda$:
>
> $$p(X = k) = \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$$
>
> 1. From the hypotheses above, Why would we conclude that : $e^\lambda = \sum^{+ \infty}_{k = 0} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$
> 2. Compute $E(X)$ and $V(X)$.
> 3. Everytime a leaves falls on the ground, the student flips a coin which gives tails with a probability $p$ and heads with probability $q = 1 - p$, $p \in (0,1)$.
>
> We note $T$ and $H$ the number of tails and heads obtained respectively.
>
> 3.1. For $k$ fixed, explain why the distribution of $T$ knowing $X = k$ is a binomial distribution and deduce the expression of $ p(X = k|H = a)$.
>
> 3.2 For $(a,n) \in \mathbb{N}^2$, compute $p(X = k, H = a)$.
>
> 3.3 Deduce the law of $H$ and its expected value.
>
> 3.4 Without computation, determine the law $T$.
>
> 3.5 Prove that $H$ and $T$ are independents.

---

**EDIT**

*After the help of David K, I decided to edit the post and write the answers of the questions I have been stuck with.*

**3.2**. Computing $p(H = a, X = k)$ :

We know that:

$ p(H = a| X = k) = \frac{p(H = a, X = k)}{p(X = k)} $

$X$ follows a Poission distribution of parameter $\lambda$, we also know that the number of heads from $k$ flips is a binaomial random variable, so we will have:

$$ 
\begin{align} p(H = a, X = k) & = p(X = k). p(H = a| X = k) \\
& =  \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}C^{a}_k p^k (1-p)^{k - a} 
\end{align}
$$

**3.3**. Applying the result of question 1, we get: 
$$p(H = a) = \frac{(q\lambda)^{a}}{a!}e^{-q\lambda} $$

$H$ follows a Poisson distribution of parameter $(q\lambda)$, its expected value is $(q\lambda)$.

**3.4**. T is the number of tails from $k$ flips, it is also a binomial distribution, applying the result of question 1 again, with the probability of $T$ is $p$, we get :
$$ p(T = b) = \frac{(p\lambda)^{b}}{b!}e^{-p\lambda} $$

**3.5**. $H$ and $T$ are independents:

$$
\begin{align}
p(H = a, T = b) & = p(H = a, X = a + b) \\
& = p(H = a| X = a + b).p(X = a + b) \\
& = C^{a}_{a+b} p^a (1-p)^{a+b-a}. \frac{\lambda^{a+b}}{(a+b)!}e^{-\lambda} \\
& = \frac{(a + b)!}{a! b!} p^a q^b \frac{\lambda^a \lambda^b}{(a+b)!} e^{-\lambda( p + q )} \\
& = \frac{(q\lambda)^a}{a!} e^{- q\lambda} . \frac{(p\lambda)^b}{b!} e^{- p\lambda} \\
& = p(H = a).p(T = b)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You appear to have a typo. $$\require{cancel} p(H=a|X=k) = C_k^ap^a(1-p)^{\color{red}{k} \cancel{p} -a}$$

Comment: There's no such thing as $H\cap T$, because $H$ and $T$ are not events. What's the actual definition of independence for two _random variables_?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Two_random_variables

Comment: I don't think your expression for $p(H=a)$ is correct.  $k$ is not a given constant.  I think you need to replace each occurrence of $k$ by $p$.

Comment: @saulspatz, in the problem I have, it is mentioned that $k$ is fixed. I just did not write it, which I should have done.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, I could not determine the joint probability $p(H = n_1,T = n_2)$ so I can check if it is equal to $p(H = n_1).p(T = n_2)$. In this case, $H$ and $T$ will be independent, the probability of having a number of heads does not affect the probability of the number of tails.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Ah! Thank you.

Comment: In the problem you have stated here, the fixed parameters are $m$ and $p$. It makes no sense in this context to treat $k$ as a fixed parameter when computing $P(H=a)$. We don’t know what your previous exercise said, so we cannot say how it should apply, but evidently you are not showing the correct application of the earlier exercise.

Comment: @DavidK I just edited the question and posted the whole problem. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @saulspatz I just posted the whole problem to avoid lack of information.

Comment: In the problem, there is no $m$.  That's a different problem.  Here, the leaves fall according to a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$, so the parameters of the problem are $\lambda$ and $p$.  Then you have $$p(H = a| X = k) = \frac{p(X = a, H = a)}{p(X = a)}$$ Really?  You need to proofread what you type so we can understand what your difficulty is.  This just seems to be written at random.  I'm sure it's not, but I find it hard to understand where you're stuck.

Comment: @saulspatz I have removed the $m$. I am stuck with the last 3 questions. I am not sure of my answers of 3.3 and 3.4 as I don't know how to answer the last one as well. What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: Ok, $k$ is fixed for part of 3.1 because the question says so. After you are done with that part of 3.1 you no longer can use $k$ as if it were already set that way. In particular, it is absolutely the wrong variable name where you tried to use it in 3.2. The other half of 3.2 is wrong as well.

Comment: To your credit, you have made much more effort than many people with similar questions. And because of that we are able to criticize errors, but that is a good thing. In general you seem to be having trouble keeping track of things (sometimes even within a formula, hence the “need to proofread” comment). Consistently using variable names, knowing how they are defined and when those definitions go “out of scope” and become invalid, is an important skill to work on.

Comment: @DavidK Thank you, I am still stuck with it if you have ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3.2, you are asked to find $P(X=k, H=a),$ not $P(X=a,H=a).$ 
I think if you account for the $k$ and $a$ more carefully you will get a different answer than currently shown at the time I write this.

For 3.3, it is true that you can apply the result of problem 1, but for $X$ the parameter of the Poisson distribution is $\lambda$ instead of $m$
(it looks like you understood--or guessed--that part correctly)
and when $X=n$ then $H$ has a binomial distribution with parameters $n,p$ -- the same statement that is made about $Y$ in problem 1. So you are correct to substitute $\lambda$ for $m,$ but you should not substitute anything for $p$
(or to be pedantic, you should substitute the variable named $p$ from problem 3 for the variable named $p$ in the problem 1, but the effect on the notation is the same).

Also for 3.3, you can either write $P(H=k)$ so you are using the variable $k$ in the exact same way as in problem 1,
or you can write $P(H=a)$ and substitute $a$ where $k$ was used in problem 1.
Or you can use some other variable instead of either $k$ or $a$, as long as you don't write $P(H=\lambda)$ or $P(H=p)$ (since in those cases you would be using one name for two different things).

For 3.4, **think!** Is it possible that $H$ and $T$ are the same, and that $H=a$ and $T=a$? Is it possible that **neither** $H$ nor $T$ is equal to $a$, for example
$H=a-1$ and $T=a+1$? Then by what logic can you possible say that
$P(T=a) = 1 - P(H=a)$?

For 3.5, you have the wrong notation. $P(H.T)$ doesn't mean anything.
What you want to show is
$$ P(H = a, T = b) = P(H=a) P(T=b). $$

The event $H=a, T=b$ is exactly the same event as $X=a+b, H=a.$
So if you have found the correct formulas for
$P(X=k,H=a),$ for $P(H=a),$ and for $P(T=b),$ this part of the question
almost answers itself.

Comment: Accepted answer, thank you for your help. I have just edited the post and put my answers, I hope they are correct this time.

Answer (score 1):

If $X\sim\mathrm{Pois}(m)$ and $Y$ conditioned on $\{X=n\}$ has $\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$ distribution then for any nonnegative integer $k$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y=k) &= \sum_{n=k}^\infty \mathbb P(Y=k\mid X=n)\mathbb P(X=n)\\
&= \sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom nk p^k(1-p)^{n-k} e^{-m}\frac{m^n}{n!}\\
&= \left(\frac p{1-p}\right)^k \frac{e^{-m}}{k!}\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{(m(1-p))^n}{(n-k)!}\\
&= \left(\frac p{1-p}\right)^k \frac{e^{-m}}{k!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(m(1-p))^{n+k}}{k!}\\
&= (mp)^k\frac{e^{-m}}{k!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(m(1-p))^n}{n!}\\
&=(mp)^k\frac{e^{-m}}{k!} e^{m(1-p)}\\
&= e^{-mp}\frac{(mp)^k}{k!},
\end{align}
so that $Y\sim\mathrm{Pois}(mp)$.

For the second question, if $\mathbb P(X=k)=\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$ is a probability distribution over the nonnegative integers, then we must have $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb P(X=k)=1$, from which $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}=e^\lambda$. The expectation of $X$ is
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\lambda^k}{(k-1)!}e^{-\lambda} = \lambda\sum_{k=0}^\infty 
\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda} = \lambda,
$$
and the expectation of $X(X-1)$ is
$$
\mathbb E[X(X-1)] = \sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1)\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda} = \lambda^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda} = \lambda^2.
$$
Hence the variance of $X$ is
$$
\mathrm{Var}(X) = \mathbb E[X^2] - \mathbb E[X]^2 = \mathbb E[X(X-1)] + \mathbb E[X] - \mathbb E[X]^2 =\lambda^2+\lambda-\lambda^2 = \lambda.
$$

For 3), it is not clear to me what the relation between $X$ and $H,T$ is. Without that information, I cannot answer the question.

Comment: I have answered the questions you answered, I am stuck in question 3, thank you for your answer though.